# How can I get the base url with Flask / Jinja2?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a `base.html` template which I would like to use for all pages. This `base.html` contains a navigation

```
<nav>
  <li><a href="./home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="./foo">bar</a></li>
</nav>
```

This is no problem when I'm on the same level (e.g. `localhost:5000/whatever`), but when I'm in a subfolder (e.g. `localhost:5000/whatever/insert`) the links break.

This can be fixed by making the relative links absolute, e.g.

```
<nav>
  <li><a href="{{base_url}}/home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{base_url}}/foo">bar</a></li>
</nav>
```

However, I don't know how to get the `base_url`. If possible, I would like to avoid adding `base_url` to each `render_template` call. And, if possible, I would also like to avoid to set `base_url` manually.

How is this problem solved with Flask / Jinja2?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Don't worry about a base url; if `home` and `foo` are *routes in your Flask app*, use the [`url_for()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.url_for) to build your URLs instead:

```html
<nav>
  <li><a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{ url_for('foo') }}">bar</a></li>
</nav>
```

Also see the [*URL Building* section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/quickstart/#url-building) of the Flask Quickstart documentation:

> Why would you want to build URLs using the URL reversing function `url_for()` instead of hard-coding them into your templates?
>
> 1. Reversing is often more descriptive than hard-coding the URLs.
>      You can change your URLs in one go instead of needing to remember to
>      manually change hard-coded URLs.
> 2. You can change your URLs in one go instead of needing to remember to manually change hard-coded URLs
> 3. URL building handles escaping of special characters and Unicode data
>      transparently.
> 4. The generated paths are always absolute, avoiding unexpected behavior of relative paths in browsers.
> 5. If your application is placed outside the URL root, for example, in
>      `/myapplication` instead of `/`, `url_for()` properly handles that for you.

Comment: There is valid cases where you might want a full URL, for example rendering an HTML email template where asset URLs need to include your application host URL.

Comment: @kontur: sure, and then you’d still use `url_for()`, with the `_external=True` argument to get the full URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you have elements like,meta, a navbar, etc in your base.html that you would like to display across all pages in your site. You can type this at the top of each new page.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <!-- write page specific html between here -->  
{% endblock %}
```

its important to place

```
{% block content %} 
{% endblock %}
```

within you base.html file.